# NSTextField with suggestions drop-down

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

Instead of implementing my own, I am looking into reusing an existing custom NSTextField that has support for suggestions drop-down - Same as the one in the browser as you type you get a list of suggestions underneath.

Do you know any good ones?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

They're called completions. You still use a regular text field but add this:

```
control:textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem
```

The biggest problem is you need to provide the list of words that can be autocompleted.

Comment: Very cool so NSTextField already has support for it. Currently I have to hit F5 for the drop-down to appear. How do you make it appear programmatically?

Comment: Not really sure. but look up "complete:" in the documentation, there's example code called SearchField. The answer should be there somewhere.

Comment: Problem is when you're using multi-word autocompletion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674992/nstextfield-with-auto-suggestions-like-safaris-address-bar