# NSTextField with auto-suggestions like Safari's address bar?

Tags: macos, cocoa, autocomplete, safari, nstextfield

What's the easiest way to have an `NSTextField` with a "recommendation list" dynamically shown below it as the user types? Just like Safari's address bar that has a menu of some sorts (I'm pretty confident Safari's address bar suggestions is menu since it has rounded corners, blue gradient selection, and background blurring).

I've tried using [`NSTextView`'s autocompletion facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725359/nstextfield-with-suggestions-drop-down) but found it was inadequate:

- It tries to complete *words* instead of the whole text fields – in other words, selecting an autocomplete suggestion will only replace the current word.
- It nudges the autocompletion list forward and align it with the insertion point instead of keeping it align with the text field.

[image: Sample autocomplete]

In the sample screenshot above whenever I selected the autocomplete suggestion the text field only replaces `K` with the suggested item in the list, which results in `Abadi Abadi Kurniawan`.

These are what I'd like to achieve:

- Whenever a suggestion is selected, the entire text field is replaced with the suggestion.
- Keep the suggestion list aligned with the text field's left side.

Note: This is *not* a question about [adding progress indicator behind a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676555/nstextfield-like-safari-address-bar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only addresses half of your answer, but I believe you need to subclass `NSTextView` and implement the `- (NSRange)rangeForUserCompletion` method, returning the range of the entire string in the text field. This should make sure that it doesn't just autocomplete the most recently entered word.

If you want a custom menu, you're going to have to do that yourself, probably by implementing the `-controlTextDidChange:` method and displaying a custom view with a table when appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

The Safari address bar uses a separate window. Apple has example project [CustomMenus](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html) and it only takes an hour or two to customize it.

Developer session explaining what has to be done [Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/)

[image: CustomMenu]

If you want to be able to select multiple words you need to provide own FieldEditor (credits should go for someone else)

```
- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(nullable id)client;
{
    if ([client isKindOfClass:[NSSearchField class]])
    {
        if (!_mlFieldEditor)
        {
            _mlFieldEditor = [[MLFieldEditor alloc] init];
            [_mlFieldEditor setFieldEditor:YES];
        }
        return _mlFieldEditor;
    }
    return nil;
}


-  (void)insertCompletion:(NSString *)word forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange movement:(NSInteger)movement isFinal:(BOOL)flag
{
    // suppress completion if user types a space
    if (movement == NSRightTextMovement) return;

    // show full replacements
    if (charRange.location != 0) {
        charRange.length += charRange.location;
        charRange.location = 0;
    }

    [super insertCompletion:word forPartialWordRange:charRange movement:movement isFinal:flag];

    if (movement == NSReturnTextMovement)
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MLSearchFieldAutocompleted" object:self userInfo:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! but it looks a bit outdated.
Do you know anything newer? preferably swift version :) thank you

Comment: @JM_Developer Only aware of private framework Suggestion.framework Not that I have been looking. If you find something please post a new answer. https://github.com/xhruso00/MapkitSearchFieldOSX

Comment: @JM_Developer This tutorial seems to be doing something similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iuHMd0-8BI

Comment: It is the same principle - child window. Consider Lucas’s code as demo and not production ready (try having mouse inside suggestion window etc). The apple code is 95% production ready. Personally I miss those high quality sample codes before 2010